# Change background of canvas onclick

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have two loops creating many circles on a canvas. Using a timer and the doTinyCircles function, I am making the circles blink different colors. I wanted this to show up on-load, and on clicking the canvas, I want the background color to change via the randomColor() method I created. I'm getting confused by the canvas methods. I've tried using fillStyle, then strokeStyle but I keep getting a see-through background.

```
var CANVAS;
var CONTEXT;
var TIMER;

function myTimer() {
    TIMER = setInterval("doTinyCircles();", 30);
}

window.onload = function() {
    CANVAS = document.getElementById("canvas");
    CONTEXT = CANVAS.getContext("2d");
    CONTEXT.strokeRect(0, 0, CANVAS.width, CANVAS.height);
    CONTEXT.fillRect = (0, 0, CANVAS.width, CANVAS.height);
    CONTEXT.fillStyle = randomColor();
    CONTEXT.translate(32, 32);
    myTimer();
    document.getElementById("canvas").onclick = myTimer();
}

function doTinyCircles() {
CONTEXT.fillStyle = randomColor();
    for (var i = 1; i < 12; i++){
        for (var j = 0 ; j < i*1; j++){
        CONTEXT.fillStyle = randomColor();
        CONTEXT.rotate(Math.PI*2/(i*6));
        CONTEXT.beginPath();
        CONTEXT.arc(0,i*5,1.5,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        CONTEXT.fill();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually declare your `randomColor` function and make `doTinyCircles` accessible to your `myTimer` function.

```
var CANVAS;
var CONTEXT;
var TIMER;

function myTimer() {
    TIMER = setInterval("doTinyCircles();", 30);
}

CANVAS = document.getElementById("canvas");
CONTEXT = CANVAS.getContext("2d");    CONTEXT.strokeRect(0, 0, CANVAS.width, CANVAS.height);
CONTEXT.fillRect = (0, 0, CANVAS.width, CANVAS.height);
CONTEXT.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
CONTEXT.translate(32, 32);

myTimer();
    document.getElementById("canvas").onclick = myTimer();

//need to set doTinyCircles to a variable, otherwise
//myTimer won't be able to run it.
doTinyCircles = function doTinyCircles() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 12; i++){
            for (var j = 0 ; j < i*1; j++){
                CONTEXT.fillStyle = randomColor();
                CONTEXT.rotate(Math.PI*2/(i*6));
                CONTEXT.beginPath();
                        CONTEXT.arc(0,i*5,1.5,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                CONTEXT.fill();
            }
    }
}

randomColor = function randomColor() {
    var red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    return "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
}
```

Comment: I have randomColor declared in another JS file.

Comment: That would have been good to post with your original question.

Answer (score 0):

fillRect is a function, you are trying to access it like a property.

```
CONTEXT.fillRect = (0, 0, CANVAS.width, CANVAS.height);
```

should be

```
CONTEXT.fillRect(0, 0, CANVAS.width, CANVAS.height);
```

Though I still think you may have problems just changing the background color (because you are changing the drawing start position and doing an arc).
Maybe a div behind the canvas as the background color would be better.

Also, here is a good random hex color function.

```
function randomColor() {
    return '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
}
```

EDIT:
Here is one that uses a background div for the background color.
http://jsfiddle.net/725aD/1/

Comment: Here is the fiddle I was playing with, and why I say a background div may be better. http://jsfiddle.net/725aD/

Comment: Upon clicking on canvas, only sectors of the background change color. I'll have to keep tinkering, but thanks!

Comment: That is because of the drawing position change and the arc. It is why I suggested a div background.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include a fiddle that uses a background div for the background color.